# Hide and show a div depending on session

Tags: php, html, show-hide

I have an admin link with a div id "admin". Sessions are started when a user is logged in to show if it is a normal user or an admin. Normal users can't access the files for admin, but can still see the admin link.

Is there a way to make it so normal users can't see the link, using only `php` or `html`, without `jquery` or jscript or any of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using interleaved PHP & HTML with standard PHP syntax:

```
<?php
if ($user_is_an_admin) {
?>
<div id='admin'>
  Only admins can see this...
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Alternate templating syntax:

```
<?php if ($user_is_an_admin): ?>
<div id='admin'>
      Only admins can see this...
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Not interleaving, PHP only:

```
if ($user_is_an_admin) {
  echo "<div id='admin'>
      Only admins can see this...
     </div>
  ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works great. Is there possibly a way I can do it in CSS rather than going through all the pages?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use conditionals inside of your views:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['adminid'] == 1234): ?>
    <!-- Admin div goes here -->
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- Admin link goes here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```