# Hide and show a div depending on login

Tags: php, wordpress

I know I am close but I can not get this to work. I am creatign my own navigation for Login and "My Profile". I am usign the Wordpress code `<?php wp_loginout(); ?>` for the Login/Logout and that works fine. Right next to that I have the words "My Profile" and I need to show and hide this based on the login status. If they are logged in, it shows up, if they are not, then it does not show.

[I found this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964856/hide-and-show-a-div-depending-on-session) and tried the code but it does not seem to work.

Here is the code I used from that thread:

```
    <?php if ($user_is_an_admin): ?>
<div id='admin'>
      My Profile
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I realize this is to show only if the person logging in is an ADMIN but I thought I would try this first to see if i could get it to work then peruse the code for logged in or not.

So to cut to the chase, I need to know what the code would be for show/hide the "My Profile" based on weather the person is logged in or not. Regardless of there permission settings.

Answer (score 4):

Google is your friend, Quick search for "*wordpress login status*"

Yields: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

So a combination of some of the functions on that page, ive come up with this copy and paste example for you.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
<div id="user">
      My Profile
</div>
<?php elseif (is_admin()): ?>
<div id="admin">
      Admin Profile
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div id="login">
      Login...
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Your welcome ;p

Answer (score 2):

$user_is_an_admin is a dummy variable, and doesn't actually do anything.

What you are looking for in WordPress is 'is_user_logged_in()': 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
<div id='admin'>
      My Profile
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

And use the code below :

```
<?php if(isset(is_user_logged_in()))
{ 
?>
<div id='admin'>
      Show or Hide Content
</div>
<?php 
}
 ?>
```